# Can't align header (divs in divs in a container)

Tags: css, html, header, navigation

I am having trouble aligning my header. I want: [image: http://s16.postimg.org/qhuwpvh5h/site_shot.png] 
And it is displaying like this for me: [image: http://postimg.org/image/rnerz8reb/]

code:

```
<div class="banner">

<div id="portfolio"><a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></div>

<div id="logo"><a href="index4.html"><img class="logo" src="images/mira-logo2.png" alt="mira-logo"></a></div>

 <div id="about"><a href="about.html">about</a></div>

</div>

</div>
```

CSS:
    #container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%; 
    position: relative;  }

```
#top {
text-align: center;
background-color:#FFF;
text-decoration: none; }

.banner {
margin-top: 14%;
width: 100%;
background-color:#000000;
height: 28px;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
left: 0;
visibility: visible; }

/*Nav Links*/   

#portfolio {
text-align: center;
float: left;
font-family: helvetica, arial;
padding-top: 0.5%;
padding-left: 25%;
z-index: 2;
top: 0;
visibility: visible; }

#logo {
text-align: center;
position: fixed;
z-index: 2;
top: 0; }

img.logo {
padding-top: 0.8%;
width: auto;
max-height: 100%; }

#about {
text-align: center;
float: right;
padding-top: 0.5%;
font-family: helvetica, arial;
padding-right: 25%;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
top: 0;
visibility: visible; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `#logo` is `fixed`. You'll need to tell it to be at the center of the page manually, by doing this:

```
#logo {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px; /* 1/2 of the image width */
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks. How do I make the image resizable and stay in the same spot when the page/ browser size changes?

Comment: That's a bit more problematic. What I'd suggest is making the container of that logo fixed, and positioned properly, and the logo itself can then be aligned to the center using `text-align` and have a percentage width (50% etc)

Comment: It still doesn't resize though.